# cannot install numpy on python3 , ubuntu 17

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, ubuntu

```
user@user-370R4E-370R4V-370R5E-3570RE-370R5V:~$ sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-th linux-headers-4.10.0-19
  linux-headers-4.10.0-19-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-33
  linux-headers-4.10.0-33-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-35
  linux-headers-4.10.0-35-generic linux-headers-4.10.0-37
  linux-headers-4.10.0-37-generic linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-33-generic linux-image-4.10.0-35-generic
  linux-image-4.10.0-37-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-33-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-37-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  gfortran python-numpy-doc python3-dev python3-nose python3-numpy-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-numpy
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,923 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 python3-numpy amd64 1:1.12.1-1ubuntu1
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-numpy/python3-numpy_1.12.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

can any one help me?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` before downloading it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run `sudo apt-get update` before installing numpy package.
It's update packages in system.